# width="" and "height"" on img messing their visibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, width, image

Why do I need to specify the width="" and height="" of the images on this page to make it appear correctly? The images in this list that don't specify their dims aren't visible. Can I make it so that I don't need to specify?

Thanks!

http://www.rollinleonard.com/elements/index-new.php

http://jsfiddle.net/ZTDjf/
-delete the bit highlighted in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiZCr.png
-see how the result hides that image? Why is that?

Comment: Please post relevant code snippet or create a jsfiddle, that page is a mess and I can't find an image displaying the behaviour you state.

Comment: starbeamrainbowlabs -- Well, no... http://i.imgur.com/SquKx.png

Comment: Bob Davies - http://jsfiddle.net/ZTDjf/

Comment: Can you delete stuff from the fiddle so that it becomes as small as possible, but still has the problem? Anyway, I can't see the difference when removing the height and width attributes from the picture you singled out in your screen shot.

Comment: Sure! Here it is updated: http://jsfiddle.net/ZTDjf/1/

Comment: Here's how you use jsfiddle: find a *small* sample of HTML that demonstrates the problem, and put that in the upper-left rectangle. You don't need the `<DOCTYPE>` and everything; jsfiddle does that for you. Then, similarly, find the smallest subset of JavaScript you can to demonstrate the problem, and put that in the lower-left rectangle. Finally, put minimal CSS in the upper right.  Dumping your entire page into the HTML panel is kind-of useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the jquery.hover_caption.js relies on the width and height that you specified for image.

It will take the width and height values and apply to the parent DIV that the plugin created on the fly.

If you dont specify the width and height for the images, the plugin will not know what height/width it should put to the parent div. so the parent div would have `<div style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">`

That is why the image is not showing up.

see the html markup below:

```
<div style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"><h3 class="hover_caption_caption" style="padding: 0px; color: white; width: 0px; font-size: 18px; position: absolute; margin: 0px; display: none;">SPR scene 7.1 2011</h3><img title="SPR scene 7.1 2011" src="zzzthumbs/spr-scene7.1.jpg" style="z-index: -1; position: relative; font-weight: bold;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for explaining to this simpleton here what the problem is! Sorry I didn't make my fiddle more succinct.

Now that I know this, is there any way to automatically discover the width and height values without entering them individually?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you have to do is run the plugin in the "load" handler instead of "ready".

```
<script>
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('img').hover_caption();
  });
</script>
```

When you run it at "ready", the images won't have loaded yet so the plugin won't know how big they are.

Comment: Ah! That does allow them to be visible but then it breaks the function of the caption thingy. Thanks for giving me more to work with here. I'll try to form a more complete question and post again.